# Laravel Auth::check() is non responding for timed out session

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have tried to use `Auth::check()` to authenticate if the user is logged in, it works but it still works even when the session has expired which I did not expect it to work.

Please how can i check if the session has expired inside the view file and redirect to login page. It is making some session based items to produce error in my page.

I prefer running the check in the view to execute the redirect command

Thanks

Comment: I prefer create middleware to check

Comment: if they logged in with the 'remember me' feature they will be automatically logged in again

Comment: @lagbox how do i go about that

Comment: @SokHai I followed a tutorial https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-logout-on-session-expire/ using middleware but it did not make any difference

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking ... if you dont want them to be automatically logged in after a session expires and a new session is started, you would not allow them to login using the 'remember me' functionality ... if you just want to make sure their session has certain data in it you can listen to the `Login` event and then set some session vars

Comment: @lagbox how do i add the 'remember me' feature even though I would prefer them re login. Thanks

Comment: it would be a checkbox on the login form usually ... when you are logging in via `Auth::attempt` it is the second argument (boolean)